# PHP snippet to make DIV clickable hyperlink

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a code snippet in Wordpress using the Code Snippet plugin (https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/).

I want it to make a DIV on my homepage clickable so it will hyperlink to another page. The DIV I want to make clickable is `<div class="row theme-project-row"></div>`

Screenshots:

Rendered page: https://snipboard.io/AUDaho.jpg

DIV in DevTools: https://snipboard.io/zh9VZj.jpg

Any suggestions on the PHP snippet to add? I already tried finding the DIV in my theme's PHP files but I can not locate it. Sorry in advance for asking stupid questions, I am really not an advanced user but I sincerely would like some help.

Thanks in advance I would really appreciate it.

Comment: if `theme-project-row` is a custom class, you could use javascript to do this.

Comment: Can you give me a step by step guide on how to do this @RamondeVries ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would attempt it using a `snippet`. Make sure to 'activate' it when you save.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<script>

window.onload=function() {
  console.log("WE GOT window.onload")
  let div = document.getElementById('theme-project').querySelector('.theme-project-row');
  console.log("WE GOT div:", div)

  // give it a clickable style
  div.style.cursor='pointer';
  div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    location.href='home-page.html'; // or whatever link
  }
}

</script>
<?php } );
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply! I added this snippet and activated it, unfortunately it did not make the div clickable. Maybe it requires more info form the top of the divs? I see in your snippet you guide it from earlier divs.  Here's a screenshot: https://snipboard.io/fZK0tG.jpg

Comment: Oops, I had a small typo, and corrected my answer. Can you try that?

Comment: Sorry @Kinglish it did not work :( Tried your edited snippet and removed all cache. The nippet is valid but it does not change the web page outcome.

Comment: Goodness! I simplified it, and put some console.log statements in there. Can you try and let me know if those do anything?

Comment: Nothing changed im sorry! I don't see the link I set appearing in DevTools as well. (I set www.google.com to try the snippet) https://snipboard.io/6PNuDs.jpg Again, thank you for helping, I really appreciate it! @Kinglish

Comment: Maybe you can try to make the images set in the DIV clickable? https://snipboard.io/TDAFlG.jpg